# ng-if inside ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

SOLUTION FOUND: I was just using a version of angular that did not support ng-if.

Here is a simplified version of my code.

First, my partial:

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="poll in polls">
        <div ng-if="poll.moduleState  === 'not-voted'">
          <!-- Template 1 -->
          Not Voted: {{poll.name}}
        </div>
        <div ng-if="poll.moduleState === 'voted'">
          <!-- Template 2 -->
          Voted: {{poll.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
function ViewPollsCtrl($q, $scope, $http) {

  $scope.polls =
            [
                {
                    "name": "module1",
                    "moduleState": "not-voted"
                },
                {
                    "name": "module2",
                    "moduleState": "voted"
                }
            ];
}
```

I expect the output to be

```
Not Voted: module1
Voted: module2
```

But instead the output is

```
Not Voted: module1
Voted: module1
Not Voted: module2
Voted: module2
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? Is it because of a weird interaction between ng-if inside ng-repeat?

Edit: Here is an image of what I am seeing
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine with your code.

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  
  $scope.polls =
            [
                {
                    "name": "module1",
                    "moduleState": "not-voted"
                },
                {
                    "name": "module2",
                    "moduleState": "voted"
                }
            ];
          
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="poll in polls">
        <div ng-if="poll.moduleState  === 'not-voted'">
          <!-- Template 1 -->
          Not Voted: {{poll.name}}
        </div>
        <div ng-if="poll.moduleState === 'voted'">
          <!-- Template 2 -->
          Voted: {{poll.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tested it in Js-fiddle as well and found that it worked, but oddly enough, it doesnt work in my own program. Could it have something to do with controllers? The only difference between my code and yours is how the controller is declared.

Comment: I get the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: what is the resource ? controller?

Comment: Thats the entire message.... How can I know? On the right it says :3000/#/viewPolls which is the url to the page

Comment: take a screen shot and post here

Comment: Ok, If I post a link to my github would that be helpful?